# XML .xsd Schema - Enforce Relationship

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the following xml which I validate with an .xsd schema.

I can enforce that each of the product names in xProfile exists and is defined in the first half of the xml by using ref and key ref.

I would like to enforce that each 'xProduct' contains an entry for each of the products defined in the top half of the xml but don't know how to do this or if this is possible?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <profiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="\\schema.xsd">
        <products>
            <product name="product01" bool_setting="true">
                <code name="AAA"/>
                <code name="BBB"/>
            </product>
            <product name="product02" bool_setting="true">
                <code name="CCC"/>
                <code name="DDD"/>
            </product>
            <product name="product03" bool_setting="true">
                <code name="EEE"/>
            </product>
            <product name="product04" bool_setting="false">
                <code name="FFF"/>
                <code name="GGG"/>
            </product>
            <product name="product05" bool_setting="false">
                <code name="HHH"/>
            </product>
            <product name="product06" bool_setting="false">
                <code name="III"/>
            </product>
        </products>
        <xProfile name="name_one">
            <products>
                <product name="product01" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product02" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product03" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product04" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product05" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product06" aNumber="1"/>
            </products>
        </xProfile>
            <xProfile name="name_one">
            <products>
                <product name="product01" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product02" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product03" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product04" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product05" aNumber="1"/>
                <product name="product06" aNumber="1"/>
            </products>
        </xProfile>
    </profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your schema here without which its difficult to find out . 
Otherwise there are two ways where you can restrict this : 
Use derivation in XML , one is derivation by extension , second is derivation by restriction as given below :
http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter13.html

Comment: At the moment my schema for this example doesn't contain anything. I'm not sure why that would affect how to enforce the constraint I want?